How to change the font family in material v18
I am following the documentation of
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-theme
// From documentation

$theme: mat.define-theme((
  
  typography: (
    brand-family: 'Open Sans',
    bold-weight: 900
  ),
));

html {
    @include mat.core-theme($theme);
    @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
    @include mat.all-component-typographies($theme);
}

and tried the answer from
Font-Family Change on Angular Material
//  Answer based on stackoverflow

$my-theme: mat.define-theme($config: (
    typography: (
      plain-family: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
      brand-family: '"Open Sans", sans-serif',
    ),
  ),);

  :root {
    @include mat.all-component-typographies($my-theme);
  }

none of the options worked. Let me know how to change the font family on material v18
PS: Do not comment there are already answers. Those are for previous versions which do not work for v18

https://material.angular.io/guide/typography have you checked the guide on the typography? give us an example on where you tried to use it.

The problem is that by default, the typography only applies to the Material components and not to the rest of the app. To fix it, include the typography hierarchy mixin in your styles.scss:
@include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme);

This exposes additional CSS classes such as mat-typography. In your index.html, you can use this class on the body element to apply your typography to the whole app:
<body class="mat-typography">
  <!-- ... -->
</body>

You don't need to add this class to the body, you can add it to any element. This also allows more granular use of the typography.

body { ... } is not the right solution. @include mat.typography-hierarchy($theme); worked. Thanks. Why the documentation is not clear?

This is my general setup for Angular Material v18 which works:
{
  ...
  dependencies: {
    ...
    "@angular/material": "^18.2.2",
    ...
  }
}

Then in my src/styles.scss
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@include mat.core();

$custom-font-family: 'My Custom Font', sans-serif;
$custom-font-size: 16;
$custom-font-weight: 500;

$custom-body-typography-level: mat.m2-define-typography-level(
  $font-size: #{$custom-font-size}px,
  $font-weight: #{$custom-font-weight},
  $line-height: 1.3
);

$custom-typography: mat.m2-define-typography-config(
  $font-family: $custom-font-family,
  $body-1: $custom-body-typography-level,
);

$custom-app-primary: mat.m2-define-palette(mat.$m2-indigo-palette);
$custom-app-accent: mat.m2-define-palette(mat.$m2-cyan-palette, A200, A100, A400);

// Define the theme object.
$custom-theme: mat.m2-define-light-theme((
  color: (
    primary: $custom-app-primary,
    accent: $custom-app-accent,
  ),
  density: (
    scale: 0,
  ),
  typography: $custom-typography,
));

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($custom-theme);
}


At last, in angular.json
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    "your-project-name": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          ...
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

